# How do I use a 3 legged phototransistor?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, transistor

I have searched the Internet and found the following circuit to use with my phototransistor but it is not working, I can say so because all analog input i get is 1023 even if i have covered it totally, I have include the phototransistor and the diagram can anyone tell why is it not working!
I used this webpage to check my sensor and it works-[I used this page](https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor/testing-an-ir-sensor)

I have used 10kohm resistor.

[image: Image of circuit]

[This is my phototransistor](http://xmghdm.en.ec21.com/IR_LED_Infrared_LED_IR--3179904_3180358.html)

[image]

Comment: I have used a 10kohm resistor

Comment: What is your infra-red light source?  That PTX won't respond well to ambient light.

Comment: halogen lamp and tv remote both @Majenko

Comment: Showing just the relevant portion of your image makes it **MUCH** easier to view

Comment: Thanks Russell @RussellMcMahon do You have any idea about this problem, also I got new info when i made the test circuit as said by this webpage - https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor/testing-an-ir-sensor it works fine

Comment: That's not a phototransistor. Phototransistors do not have a "supply voltage" or a "work frequency".

Comment: It happens to be an IR phototransistor @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: It may *contain* a phototransistor, but it is *not* a phototransistor.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the same phototransistor so called ir sensor is available at adafruit, so it is basically phototransistor which has a peak sensitivity of Infrared spectrum -http://www.adafruit.com/product/157

Comment: You can also check the data sheet below and will you pls care to look at my previous question and maybe tell me an answer. Thanks! @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: I'm okay with people looking at you sideways with big question marks over their heads, so feel free to believe that you have a phototransistor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25119/discussion-between-aadityacool-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The website says so and also I use codes for phototransistor and its working is same and is is doing same thing that a phototransistor is supposed to be

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably generic data sheet is [**HERE**](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Datasheets-SL3/DSASL0044436.pdf)
That is for an AT156 but yours may be an AT138/HT138 based on an ad some years ago from the same seller when they said they had 10,000 for sale.

Basic information here and more in the data sheet.

[image]

Comment: Following the same guide I am now able to decode my remote signals, though thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

First that is not even a photo resistor 2nd you have to put one wire positive and the other negitive and the last one plug it into any other gpio pin